# h1 custom border-bottom width instead of full-width

Tags: css

This is what I need:

[image]

This is what I have:

```
h1 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

and the borders are full-width...

Is there a nice solution?

Comment: use display:table-cell on h1 tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use display: inline-block

`display: inline-block;`

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jup7qvt6/)

Comment: h1 {    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block; }  and text-align: center for parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/SHABU89/jup7qvt6/1/)

```
<div class="full-width">
<h1>Lorem</h1><br/>
<h1>Loerm ipsum h1</h1><br/>
<h1>Other Loerm ipsum h1</h1>
</div>

h1{
   border-bottom: 3px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;

}
.full-width{
  text-align:center
}
```